# how to save dates in binary file then read the file and print it?

Tags: c++, c

i edit it i couldnt answer my own question

```
// Cajero.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "MiLib.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int Menu1();
void Baja(FILE* fp);
void Modificar(FILE* fp);
void Retiro(FILE* fp,FILE* as);
void Deposito(FILE* fp);
void ImprimeC(FILE* fp);
void ImprimeT(FILE* as);
void CuentaE(FILE* fp);
void CuentaN(CUENTA* Dar,FILE* fp);
void DarAlta(FILE* fp);
int Menu2();
void Tranfe(FILE* fp);
void Consu(FILE* fp);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CUENTA cuenta;
    TRANSFE temp;
    FILE *fptr,*asdf;
    int opcion = 0,opcion2=0;
    fptr = fopen("Cuentas.db", "r+b");
    if(fptr == NULL) {
        fptr = fopen("Cuentas.db", "w+b");
        return 1; 
    }
    asdf = fopen("Transferencias.db", "r+b");
    if(asdf == NULL) {
        asdf = fopen("Transferencias.db", "w+b");
        return 1; 
    }




    while(opcion < 6) {
        opcion=0;
        opcion = Menu1();
        switch(opcion) {
            case 1: {
                Retiro(fptr,asdf);
                break;           
             }
             case 2: {
                 Deposito(fptr);
                  break;
             } // fin del caso 2 borrar
             case 3:{
                    Tranfe(fptr);
                    break;
                    }
             case 4:{
                    Consu(fptr);
                    break;
                    }
             case 5: {
                 opcion2=0;
                 opcion2=Menu2();
                 switch(opcion2){
                    case 1:{
                        DarAlta(fptr);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        Baja(fptr);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3:{
                        Modificar(fptr);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 4:{
                        ImprimeC(fptr);
                        getche();
                        ImprimeT(asdf);
                        getch();
                        break;
                    }   
                 }
                 break;
              } 


             default : {
                 break;
              } 
        } 
    } 

    fclose(fptr);
    fclose(asdf);

    return 0;


}

void ImprimeT(FILE* as){
     TRANSFE temp;
     system("cls"); 
     printf("                   L I S T A    D E   T R A N S F E R E N C I A S\n\n");
     printf("Cuenta    Dinero       Movimiento  Fecha \n");
     printf("------- ----------- ------------- --------------------\n");
     rewind(as);
    do {
    fflush (as);
    fread( &temp, sizeof(TRANSFE), 1, as );
    if( feof(as) ) break; 

    if (temp.baja == 0) {
        printf("%d    %f   %s    %s\n", 
             temp.numero, temp.dinero, temp.movi, 
             asctime(&temp.timeinfo)); // pass address of struct tm to asctime

        fflush (as);
    } 
 } while(TRUE);
     return;


}

void Baja(FILE* fp) {

     int baja, nip ,existe = FALSE;
     fpos_t Fpos; 
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tOpcion de baja cuenta\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta a dar de baja -> ");
     scanf("%d", &baja);
     rewind(fp);

     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(baja == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);
          if(nip == temp.nip) {


            if(temp.baja == 0) {
                temp.baja = 1; // lo marco como baja logica
                fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
                fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                printf("\n\nCuenta: %d dado de BAJA\n", temp.numero);
                } else {
                   printf("\t\tEsta Cuenta ya fue dado de baja\n");
            }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; // salida del if
        }else{

            printf("\n\t\tNIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            Baja(fp);
          }
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getche();
        return;
     }
     return;
}

void Modificar(FILE* fp){

     int cuenta,nip=0,op=0, existe = FALSE;
     char nombre[50];
     fpos_t Fpos; // direccion del registro
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tOpcion de modificar cuenta\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta  -> ");
     scanf("%d", &cuenta);
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(cuenta == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);

          if(nip==temp.nip){

              do{
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\n\n\n\t\t1.- Nombre");
                    printf("\n\t\t2.- NIP");
                    printf("\n\t\t3.- RFC");
                    printf("\n\t\t4.- Regresar al menu");
                    printf("\n\n\t\tQue desea modificar ->");
                    scanf("%d",&op);
                    system("cls");

                    switch(op){
                        case 1:{
                           printf("\n\t\t Nuevo nombre ->");
                           scanf(" %[^\n]",temp.nombre);
                           fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
                           fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                           printf("\n\t\t Modificacion efectuada con exito");
                           break;
                           }
                        case 2:{
                           printf("\n\t\tNuevo NIP ->");
                           scanf("%d",&temp.nip);
                           fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
                           fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                           printf("\n\t\tModificacion efectuada con exito");
                           break;
                           }
                        case 3:{
                           printf("\n\t\tNuevo RFC ->");
                           scanf(" %[^\n]",&temp.RFC);
                           fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
                           fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                           printf("\n\t\tModificacion efectuada con exito");
                           break;

                               }
                        default:{
                           return;
                          }
                    }

              }while(op<4);

              fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
              fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );

          }else{
            printf("\n\t\tNIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            Modificar(fp);

          }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; // salida del if
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getch();
        return;
     }
     return;

}

void Retiro(FILE* fp,FILE* as){


     int cuenta,nip=0, existe = FALSE;
     float retiro=0.0,saldoactual=0.0;
     TRANSFE transfe;
     time_t rawtime;
     struct tm * timeinfo;
     fpos_t Fpos; 
     CUENTA temp;



     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tOpcion de retiro a cuenta\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta  -> ");
     scanf("%d", &cuenta);
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(cuenta == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);

          if(nip==temp.nip){
              printf("\n\t\tSaldo actual-> %f",temp.dinero);
              printf("\n\t\tCifra a retirar->");
              scanf("%f",&retiro);
              saldoactual=(float)temp.dinero-retiro;
              if(saldoactual<0.0){
                  printf("Insuficientes fondos");
                  getch();
                  Retiro(fp,as);
              }else{
                    temp.dinero=saldoactual;
                    fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
                    fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                    printf("\n\t\tRetiro efectuado con exito");

                    transfe.numero=temp.numero;
                    transfe.baja=temp.baja;
                    transfe.dinero=retiro;
                    time ( &rawtime );
                    transfe.timeinfo = *localtime ( &rawtime ); // copy into struct tm

                    strncpy(transfe.movi, "retiro", MAXLEN); // copy into array

                    fwrite(&transfe,sizeof(TRANSFE),1,as);

                    getch();
                    return;
              }
          }else{
            printf("NIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            Retiro(fp,as);
          }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; 
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getch();
        return;
     }
     return;

}

void Deposito(FILE* fp){

     int cuenta,nip=0, existe = FALSE;
     float deposito;
     fpos_t Fpos; // direccion del registro
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tOpcion de deposito a cuenta\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta  -> ");
     scanf("%d", &cuenta);
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(cuenta == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);

          if(nip==temp.nip){
              printf("\n\t\tSaldo actual-> %f",temp.dinero);
              printf("\n\t\tCifra a depositar->");
              scanf("%f",&deposito);
              deposito=temp.dinero+deposito;

              temp.dinero=deposito;
              fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
              fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
              printf("\n\t\tDeposito efectuado con exito");

          }else{
            printf("NIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            Deposito(fp);
          }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; // salida del if
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getche();
        return;
     }
     return;

}

void ImprimeC(FILE* fp) {
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls"); // ordena limpiar la pantalla
     printf("                   L I S T A    D E    C U E N T A S\n\n");
     printf("Cuenta  Nombre                  Dinero            RFC \n");
     printf("------- -------------------- ------------- --------------------\n");
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break; // salida del while
        if(temp.baja == 0) {
            printf("%7d %-20s %9.2f     %-20s\n", temp.numero, temp.nombre, temp.dinero,temp.RFC);
        } // fin frl if
     } while(TRUE); // fin del for que muestra los datos en pantalla
     return;
}

void CuentaE(FILE* fp){

     int cuenta,nip=0, existe = FALSE;
     float deposito;
     fpos_t Fpos; // direccion del registro
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tDar de alta cuenta existente\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta  -> ");
     scanf("%d", &cuenta);
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(cuenta == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);

          if(nip==temp.nip){
              temp.baja=0;
              fsetpos( fp, &Fpos );
              fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
              printf("\n\t\tCuenta dada de alta con exito");

          }else{
            printf("NIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            DarAlta(fp);
          }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; // salida del if
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getch();
        return;
     }
     return;

}

int Menu1(){

    int op;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t1.-Retiro de cuenta");
    printf("\n\t\t2.-Depositar a cuenta");
    printf("\n\t\t3.-Transferencia");
    printf("\n\t\t4.-Colsulta de saldo");
    printf("\n\t\t5.-Opciones de cuentas");
    printf("\n\t\t6.-Salir");
    printf("\n\n\t\tOpcion----->");
    scanf("%d",&op);

    system("cls");

    return op;

}

void CuentaN(CUENTA* Dat,FILE* fp){

    int existe=FALSE;
    rewind(fp);

    system("cls"); 

    CUENTA temp;
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\tNumero -> ");
    scanf("%d", &Dat->numero);
    do {


        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );

        if( feof(fp) ) break; // salida del while

        if(temp.numero==Dat->numero){
            printf("\n\t\tCuenta existente por favor elegir otro numero de cuenta");
            getche();
            existe=TRUE;
            return;         
        }   

    } while(TRUE);

    if(!existe){

        printf("\t\tNIP -> ");
        scanf("%d", &Dat->nip);
        printf("\t\tNombre -> ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &Dat->nombre);
        printf("\t\tDeposito -> ");
        scanf("%f", &Dat->dinero);
        printf("\t\tRFC -> ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &Dat->RFC);
        printf("\n");
        Dat->baja = 0;

        printf("\n\t\tCuenta creada con exito");
        getche();

    }else{
        return;
    }

    do {
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break; 

    } while(TRUE);

    return;

}

void DarAlta(FILE* fp){

     int op;
     CUENTA cuenta;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n\t\t1.- Dar de alta cuenta existente");
     printf("\n\t\t2.- Dar de alta cuenta inexsistente");
     printf("\n\t\t3.- Regresar al menu");
     printf("\n\n\t\tQue desea modificar ->");
     scanf("%d",&op);

     switch(op){
     case 1:{
            CuentaE(fp);
            break;
            }
     case 2:{
            CuentaN(&cuenta,fp);
            fwrite( &cuenta, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp);
            break;
            }
     default:{

             return;
             }
     }

     system("cls");

     return;
}

int Menu2(){

    int op2;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t1.-Dar de alta cuenta");
    printf("\n\t\t2.-Dar de baja cuenta");
    printf("\n\t\t3.-Modificar cuenta");
    printf("\n\t\t4.-Listar cuentas");
    printf("\n\t\t5.-Regresar al menu anterior");
    printf("\n\n\t\tOpcion----->");
    scanf("%d",&op2);

    system("cls");

    return op2;

}

void Tranfe(FILE* fp){

    int cuenta,cuentatr,nip, existe = FALSE,existetr =FALSE;
    float trans=0.0,saldon;
    fpos_t Fpos,Fpostr; // direccion del registro
    CUENTA temp,temp2;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\tOpcion de transferencia\n");
    printf("\t\tCuenta que tranfiere -> ");
    scanf("%d", &cuenta);
    rewind(fp);

    do{
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );

        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(temp.numero==cuenta){
             printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
             scanf("%d",&nip);

             if(temp.nip==nip){
                 printf("\n\t\tSaldo actual-> %f",temp.dinero);
                 printf("\n\t\tDinero a transferir ->");
                 scanf("%f",&trans);
                 if(temp.dinero-trans>=0){
                     temp.dinero=temp.dinero-trans;

                 }else{
                     printf("\n\n\t\tCuenta con insuficiente dinero");
                     getche();
                     Tranfe(fp);
                 }
                 printf("\n\n\t\tCuenta a transferir ->");
                 scanf("%d",&cuentatr);

                 rewind(fp);

                 do{
                     fgetpos(fp,&Fpostr);
                     fread( &temp2, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                     if( feof(fp) ) break;


                     if(temp2.numero==cuentatr){

                         temp2.dinero=temp2.dinero+trans;
                         fsetpos(fp,&Fpostr);
                         fwrite( &temp2, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                         fsetpos(fp,&Fpos);
                         fwrite( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
                         printf("\n\n\t\tTransferencia con exito");

                         existetr = TRUE;
                         return;

                     }


                 }while(TRUE);
                 if(!existetr) {
                     printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
                     getche();
                     Tranfe(fp);
                 }


             }else{
            printf("\n\n\tNIP equivocado");
            getche();
            Tranfe(fp);
            }
            existe = TRUE;
            break; // salida del if
        }


    }while(TRUE);

    if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getche();
        return;
     }


    return;
}

void Consu(FILE* fp){

     int cuenta,nip=0, existe = FALSE;
     float deposito;
     fpos_t Fpos; // direccion del registro
     CUENTA temp;
     system("cls");
     printf("\n\n\n");
     printf("\t\tOpcion de consulta de saldo\n");
     printf("\t\tCuenta  -> ");
     scanf("%d", &cuenta);
     rewind(fp);
     do {
        fgetpos( fp, &Fpos ); 
        fread( &temp, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fp );
        if( feof(fp) ) break;

        if(cuenta == temp.numero) {
          printf("\n\t\tNIP ->");
          scanf("%d",&nip);

          if(nip==temp.nip){
              printf("\n\t\tSaldo actual-> %f",temp.dinero);
              getche();

          }else{
            printf("NIP equivocado intente de nuevo");
            getche();
            Consu(fp);
          }
          existe = TRUE;
          break; // salida del if
        }
     } while( TRUE );
     if(!existe) {
        printf("\t\tLa cuenta no existe en el archivo");
        getche();
        return;
     }
     return;

}
```

Comment: It's clearly "crashed". What was the error message? Which line does it crash on?

Comment: localtime returns a pointer.  You cannot meaningfully save a pointer to a file.  You need to save the value it points to like `timeinfo = *localtime(&rawtime)`.  It might be simpler to save and load the rawtime and call localtime on that.  The rawtime is a time_t which is designed for strorage in binary files.

Comment: typedef struct{
 int numero;
 float dinero;
 int baja;
 struct tm* timeinfo;
 char* movi;



}TRANSFE;

this is struct witch i want to save the local time

Comment: You have the same problem with movi.  You need to change to this: `typedef struct{ int numero; float dinero; int baja; struct tm timeinfo; char movi[MAXLEN]; }TRANSFE`  #define MAXLEN 100 or something.  Then strncpy to movi before writing.

Comment: but i cannot do this transfe.movi="hello"; it dont compile :S

Comment: plz help i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You cannot meaningfully save and load pointers.  Change all your pointers to struct values or arrays before writing.

Declarations

```
            #define MAXLEN 100 // set to maximum length you expect movi to need
            typedef struct {
                int numero; 
                float dinero; 
                int baja; 
                struct tm timeinfo; // struct tm, not pointer to struct tm
                char movi[MAXLEN]; // character array, not pointer
            } TRANSFE;
```

To write

```
            transfe.numero=temp.numero;
            transfe.baja=temp.baja;
            transfe.dinero=retiro;
            time ( &rawtime );
            transfe.timeinfo = *localtime ( &rawtime ); // copy into struct tm

            strncpy(transfe.movi, "retiro", MAXLEN); // copy into array

            fwrite(&transfe,sizeof(TRANSFE),1,as);
```

To read

```
do {
    fflush (as);
    fread( &temp, sizeof(TRANSFE), 1, as );
    if( feof(as) ) break; 

    if (temp.baja == 0) {
        printf("%d    %f   %s    %s\n", 
             temp.numero, temp.dinero, temp.movi, 
             asctime(&temp.timeinfo)); // pass address of struct tm to asctime

        fflush (as);
    } 
 } while(TRUE);
```

You probably don't need the fflush calls either.

Some more ideas:

It is unclear to me that feof after fread will reliably detect eof without discarding the last record.  I recommend you change all your loops from

```
do {
    fflush (as);
    fread( &temp, sizeof(TRANSFE), 1, as );
    if( feof(as) ) break; 
    // do something
 } while(TRUE);
```

To instead use this:

```
while (TRUE) {
    if (fread( &temp, sizeof(TRANSFE), 1, as ) != 1)
        break;
    // do something
 }
```

Also, if you have changed the declaration of TRANSFE the previously written data files will be incompatible.  Delete them and make new empty files.

It will help you to debug if you have some known-good data in your files.  You can use something like this to populate test data into the file so you can debug with it.

```
        FILE *fcuentas = fopen("Cuentas.db", "w+b");
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            CUENTA test = {};
            test.baja = i*100 + 1;
            test.dinero = i*100 + 2;
            test.nip = i*100 + 3;
            strcpy(test.nombre, "test nombre");
            test.numero = i*100 + 5;
            strcpy(test.RFC,"test RFC");
            fwrite( &test, sizeof(CUENTA), 1, fcuentas );
        }
        fclose(fcuentas);

        FILE *ftransferencias = fopen("Transferencias.db", "w+b");
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
        {
            TRANSFE test = {};
            test.baja = i*100 + 1;
            test.dinero = i*100 + 2;
            strcpy(test.movi, "test movi");
            test.numero = i*1000 + 5;
            time_t rawtime;
            time ( &rawtime );
            test.timeinfo = *localtime ( &rawtime ); // copy into struct tm
            fwrite( &test, sizeof(TRANSFE), 1, ftransferencias );
        }
        fclose(ftransferencias);
```

Comment: it writes the first one on the binery file but when i call the funtion again doesnt write anything or its only printing the first one

Comment: We could help you debug better if you posted the whole code that demonstrates your problem. When you are just learning c there are many traps in the language and libraries you can get hung up on.